# equal height content align 2 absolute div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used 100vh on my right side and both div position absoulute. Not sure this is the best way to construct dashboard layout. My problem is, the left sidebar seems not following the length of content of the right. I also tried 100%.

```css
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  background: #DDD;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/desutovosi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` element takes `parent` element's `height`, `#content` will increase `.app`'s `height` and `#sidebar` automatically will `100%` `height` of `.app`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.app{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100vh;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height:100%;
}
#content {
  background: #DDD;
  padding-left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  min-height:100vh;
}
ul,li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=app>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use jQuery `.height()` like this,

```
var contentHeight = $('#content').height();

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#sidebar').height(contentHeight);

});
```

hope help :)

```js
var contentHeight = $('#content').height();

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sidebar').height(contentHeight);
});
```

```css
#sidebar{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
}

body{margin:0}

li{
    padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
}

#content{
  background:#DDD;
  margin-left:100px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="sidebar">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: uh this is a dirty hack :(

Comment: i'm new code, can you tell me way this dirty ? thanks :)  !!

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your code inside an outer div, in this case **container**

**The modified code:**

```css
   
.container {
  background-color: blue;
}
#sidebar{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width: 100px;
  background:transparent;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh
}
body{
  margin:0.
}
li{
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
}
#content{
  background:#DDD;
  margin-left:100px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is that all? that's the only thing I missed?

Comment: @Alex yes..  your code is fine just a little modification was required.